# Finding upper and lower Riemann sum of $f(x) = x^2$ on $[0,a]$ with $n$ subintervals

Tags: integration

I'm struggling to find $\Delta x_i$ on this [question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6Sfc.png):

> Calculate the lower and upper Riemann sums for the function $f(x) = x^2$ on the interval $[0,a]$ (where $a>0$), corresponding to the partiition $P_n$ of $[0,a]$ into $n$ subintervals of equal length.

My approach:

Given the interval $x\in[a,b]$, partioned into $n$ subintervals of length $\Delta x_{i} = (b-a)/n$, I have $$\Delta x_{i} = \frac{a-0}{n} $$

but the [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koJ1H.png) is like this. I couldn't understand why $\Delta x = \frac{a^3}{n^3}$

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first interval is $\left[0,\frac an\right]$ and the minimum of $f$ there is $0$. The second interval is $\left[\frac an,\frac{2a}n\right]$ and the minimum of $f$ there is $\left(\frac an\right)^2$. And so on: the $k$<sup>th</sup> interval is $\left[\frac{(k-1)a}n,\frac{ka}n\right]$ and the minimum of $f$ there is $\left(\frac{(k-1)a}n\right)^2$. So, the lower sum is$$0\times\frac an+\left(\frac an\right)^2\times\frac an+\cdots+\left(\frac{(k-1)a}n\right)^2\times\frac an+\cdots+\left(\frac{(n-1)a}n\right)^2\times\frac an$$and this is equal to\begin{align}\left(\frac an\right)^3\times\left(1^2+2^2+\cdots+(n-1)^2\right)&=a^3\times\frac{(n-1)n(2n-1)}{6n^3}\\&=a^3\times\frac{(n-1)(2n-1)}{6n^2}.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just to make sure, $a^3/n^3 is coming inside the sum and it doesn't equal to deltaX ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.